# How to decode returned function from REST API with php

Tags: php, function, rest, api

I'm making an request to a rest api and saving the result in $result. If I print the result with print_r i'm getting this output

```
(function() { return {"access_tokens":[{"token":"12345","sent_to_email":"example@mail.com","first_use_date":null},{"token":"12435","sent_to_email":"example@newmail.com","first_use_date":null}]}; });
```

The example from the API documentation is then using $result->access-tokens

but then I get the error "Trying to get property of non-object"

is there something wrong with the REST answer? or how do I encode the "function" to access the results?

for better understanding:
API https://dev.clickmeeting.com/api-doc/
I'm using "Get Access tokens". It's only working with "get conferences"

Comment: `print_r()` is really printing `(function()` at the beginning?

Comment: Most REST APIs return either JSON or XML. That looks like JSON except for the `(function { return ... ; });` stuff around it.

Comment: It's almost like JSONP, but that should return a function call, not a function expression.

Comment: yes, print_r() is really printing the (funtion() at the beginning. I get this also on other requests of this rest api

Comment: why dont i believe you? bet you lunch your adding that, what API is this?

Comment: Instead of `print_r()`, use `var_dump()`, it prints more details and less ambiguous format.

Comment: @rtfm i added the api documentation

Comment: has to be your code can you post the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake: the format was set wrong and that was causing this faulty output.

Thanks for your answers @rtfm @barmar